# IntelliJ IDEA - Eclipse .classpath files and relative locations?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, classpath

I'd like to use IntelliJ IDEA with an Eclipse project, without converting the project format.

The main problem I'm running into right now is that in my .classpath file, we have entries like:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/lib/whatever.jar" />
```

In Eclipse, that path is relative to the workspace root.  But in IntelliJ, I believe it's looking for the actual "/lib" folder on my hard drive, which obviously doesn't exist.

How can I maintain the Eclipse functionality while having IntelliJ look in the "lib" module in my project?  Is there a variable that both support?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? Its actually weird that for some of the .classpath files, Intellij recognizes the path but for some others it modifies the .classpath and changes it to full path while importing the project into Intellij.

Comment: For future projects I have found that Maven support in Eclipse, Netbeans and IntelliJ is so good, that you can effortless use any of them on a given maven project.  The native Eclipse files have previously broken on me when using different versions of Eclipse, and different flavors of the same version of Eclipse.